# In jQuery, how do I animate the "max-height" CSS property?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I can easily animate the "opacity" property

```
$("#blah").animate({ opacity: 0.5}, 1000);
```

How can I animate the max-height css property... example:

```
$("#blah").animate({ "max-height": 350}, 1000);
```

(hint, that code doesn't work)

**EDIT: To answer the questions below:**

1. There are multiple images all of css class "blah"
2. The images are of random sizes, BUT they all have max-height: 100px
3. When a user hovers over an image, I want it to animate the max-height (thereby smoothly un-restricting the height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so there is no way to do what I wanted... So I've had to make my own function to have generic "animation" function (from x to y in d milliseconds).

I wrote a blog post describing how I did it here: [Generic "Animate" function with jQuery](http://www.singingeels.com/Blogs/Nullable/2010/08/26/Generic_Animate_function_with_jQuery.aspx)

I included a demo of what it can do as well. The demo link is at the bottom of the article, or  for the impatient, you can just click [here](http://www.singingeels.com/Blogs/Nullable/2010/08/26/Articles/UserFile.aspx?FileID=d346465d-4471-45ab-a396-fb8077e9c1c0).

Comment: Someone has since asked and solved this same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901643/animate-max-width-on-img-jquery

Comment: Bad links, tested 16 Dec 2022

Answer (score 10):

This question is getting a bit old, but here's how I solved it using basic jQuery, in case someone else needs a simple solution.

In my case, I have a list of blog posts which are first rendered to the page with a `max-height` which only shows the first 4 lines of text, the rest being `overflow: hidden`.  I have a expand/collapse button which toggles the article from its collapsed form to expanded (fully displayed) and back again.

At first I tried animating the max-height property directly and, as you've discovered above, this won't work.  I also tried this with css transitions with the same disappointing result.

I also tried just setting it to a very large number like '1000em', but this made the animations look dumb as it was literally interpolating to such a large value (as you'd expect).

My solution uses scrollHeight, which is used to determine the natural height of each story once the page is loaded as follows:

```
$(function(){ // DOM LOADED

  // For each story, determine its natural height and store it as data.
  // This is encapsulated into a self-executing function to isolate the 
  // variables from other things in my script.
  (function(){

    // First I grab the collapsed height that was set in the css for later use
    var collapsedHeight = $('article .story').css('maxHeight');

    // Now for each story, grab the scrollHeight property and store it as data 'natural'        
    $('article .story').each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);

      $this.data('natural', $this[0].scrollHeight);
    });

    // Now, set-up the handler for the toggle buttons
    $('.expand').bind('click', function(){
      var $story = $(this).parent().siblings('.story').eq(0),
          duration = 250; // animation duration

      // I use a class 'expanded' as a flag to know what state it is in,
      // and to make style changes, as required.  
      if ($story.hasClass('expanded')) {
        // If it is already expanded, then collapse it using the css figure as
        // collected above and remove the expanded class
        $story.animate({'maxHeight': collapsedHeight}, duration);
        $story.removeClass('expanded');
      }
      else {
        // If it is not expanded now, then animate the max-height to the natural
        // height as stored in data, then add the 'expanded' class
        $story.animate({'maxHeight': $story.data('natural')}, duration);
        $story.addClass('expanded');
      }
    });

  })(); // end anonymous, self-executing function

});
```

To do the same with images, I would just wrap them in an outer div which is what you'll set the `max-height` and `overflow:hidden` on, just like I used div.story above.

Comment: BTW, scrollHeight is always available, so that you don't need to cache it in "data" fields.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same thing.

The answer is to use `"maxHeight"` rather than `"max-height"` ...

Comment: Both `maxHeight` and `"max-height"` will work in newer versions of jQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/9jswu7L6/1/

Comment: The question seems to be asking for a way to animate max-height with older versions of jQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/9jswu7L6/2/

Comment: @apaul34208 I read the question twice, there's no mention of the version of jQuery.  Although, I agree that in older versions, there would have to be some additional type of adjustment to make this work (also, the original question was dated 2010, but updated this year).

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should animate the height property first and when the animation has finished replace set height to auto and reset max-height to what you need it to be:

```
$("#blah").animate({ "height": 350}, 1000, function(){
  $(this).css('height','auto').css('max-height',350);
});
```

Comment: Animating the height property would stretch images that are shorter than the "max" - thx for the thought though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused by the requirement here. If you are wanting to animate something presumably it needs to be equal to the max height already. I'd do an of statement to check of an element's height equals its max height, if so remove the max-height and then animate the height. Should be the same effect

Comment: If I animate the height to, let's say, 1000... then I'm going to stretch images that are only 300px tall. --- BUT, if I animate the max-height, then tall images will grow, but the shorter ones would not grow past 300px... so it's not the same effect. (good thought though)

Comment: Ah, I see, I was not anticipating the elements to be images. I think this is the way to go. Possibly there is a function that grabs the images sizes for you to reference. Sorry I can't help more!
Note: in your edited question you say you would unrestricted the height which is slightly confusing. I understand it that you want to increase the restricted height. If the format is true you can just animate the height to 100%. I mention this to help avoid co fusion for other users

Answer (score 1):

**Pure CSS solution**

HTML

```
<div>max-height element</div>
```

css

```
div {
    max-height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;

    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -ms-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;}

div:hover {
    max-height:300px}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/zwvNY/)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just animate the addition of a class?

CSS:

```
.expanded {
   max-height: 350px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#blah").addClass("expanded", 1000);
```

You may have to add `!important` to the CSS, but on testing it worked without it.

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look at this and found that it does work.  This is what I did:

```
$("#blah").animate({"max-height": 350}, {queue: false, duration: 1000});
```

Works for max-height without any problem.