# Animate max-width on img [JQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation, resize

I have tried looking for a solution, but can't find anything good.

I am customizing a blog for a friend of mine. When it loads, I want all the img's in each post to have a max-width and max-height of 150px. When the user pushes the img, the max-values should increase to 500px, which is easy enough. The problem with my code is that I can't get an animation on it, which I want. Any help out there?

```
var cssObj = {'max-width' : '500px','max-height' : '500px;'}

$("img").click(function(){     
    $(this).css(cssObj); 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I got it working, combining two of the other answers (and removing max-width & max-height in the css-code)

```
var cssBegin = {'max-width' : '250px','max-height' : '250px;'};       
$('img').css(cssBegin);     
var cssObj = {'max-width' : '500px','max-height' : '500px;'};
 $("img").click(function(){          $(this).animate(cssObj,'slow');  });
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of using `.css()`, try using [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
var cssObj = {'max-width' : '500px','max-height' : '500px;'}

$("img").click(function(){     
    $(this).animate(cssObj,'slow'); 
});
```

Comment: Nice, the animation is working, but the max-sizes comes out wrong... The max is about 340 in width, and 275 in height... Strange!

Comment: I would examine your margins/padding to account for the 160px loss

Comment: @Øyvind: Also, is that how big the pictures actually are?

Comment: No, some are under, but other are over 500px... That's why I wanted to use max-width, and not width. I don't have much control over the blog-platform.. If I had, I probably would have done something else ...
And the padding is 20px, so it should probably not make that big a difference...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // define sizes
    var cssBegin = { width: 150, height: 150 };
    var cssMax   = { width: 500, height: 500 };

    // init images with the small size
    $('img').css(cssBegin);

    // init click event on all images
    $("img").click(function(){ 
        $(this).animate(cssMax, 'fast'); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using CSS class, you can use `toggleClass` method - Adds the specified class if it is not present, and removes the specified class if it is present, using an optional transition.

```
$("img").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass( "cssObj", 1000 );
        return false;
    });
```

See the demo here - http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/

Comment: what CSS class is he using?  Also toggling the class provides no animation, which is the point of the question.

Comment: "var cssObj = {'max-width' : '500px','max-height' : '500px;'}" I was referring to this class. Also, toggling does provide an optional animation.

Comment: ok, on the animation, but no `var cssObj` is not a class, it is a javascript object.